# Visual Studio with GitHub: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid

Tags: visual-studio, github

I want to clone my repository to compile and improve it, with Visual Studio Community 2017.

On command line I would type `git clone git@github.com:aegif/CmisSync.git`

Visual Studio has a `Team Explorer` view with a `Clone` button, but it does not seem to work as I would expect, it shows errors:
[image: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid]

So I specified a scheme:
[image: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified]

So I specify a port:
[image: Git failed with a fatal error. Could not read from remote repository]

... which I guess is caused by Visual Studio trying to connect without bothering to authenticate me or creating SSH keys first.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this version of Visual Studio does not include GitHub integration.

First, click `Tools`>`Get tools and features` and install `GitHub extension for Visual Studio`:

[image]

Then on the `Clone` link under `GitHub`, not the one under `Local Git repositories`:

[image]

Now you can easily select your GitHub repository and clone it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub extension for Visual Studio sometimes crashes or makes Visual Studio slower, so another option is:

1. Download Git from the [official website](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. Install Git for Windows
3. Using it, clone your repository
4. Open the local repository from Visual Studio
5. Perform all Git operations with Git for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I try to clone a repo from bitbucket. I just open sourcetree and cloned it. Then switched to Visual Studio 2019 to open it.